# Webcam framerate different in Cheese/Jitsi to framerate in Guvcvuew?

Tags: video, webcam, cheese, framerate, guvcview

The [AnkerWork B600](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjhIBVqMK-I) is a webcam that was released recently.

When I view the webcam using the [Guvcview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guvcview) application, the framerate is reasonable (at about 23 fps) with the resolution at 2560 x 1440 and the camera output at RGB3-RGB3. However when I view the webcam using Cheese the framerate drops to about 1 fps, which isn't meaningfully usable. Why is this difference happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Since there is not drive from the maker of that product probably not. Contact the maker and ask them.

Comment: @David Thanks for your thoughts there. There *is* a driver for the camera. The issue is the framerate.